# Umbraco update error from 7.5.14 to 7.6.4

Tags: c#, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have updatet a Umbraco site from 7.5.14 to 7.6.4 via Nuget in VS2017, but after the update I get this error:

Could not load type 'umbraco.presentation.umbracobase.RestExtension' from assembly 'umbraco, Version=1.0.6396.36631, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

What is the problem or what must i do to remove the problem?

Comment: Check out this thread on our, maybe it will help: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/46457-Umbraco-7-could-not-load-RestExtension

Comment: You have to remove "umbraco.presentation" library, do you have it in bin folder? which page gives you this error? did you merge web.config correctly?